# Apple Watch OS 2.0 Gyroscope api availability

Tags: xcode7, core-motion, watchos-2

I was wondering if a Apple Developer can clarify whether or not, the API will be available.

There is a bit of speculation going around on the internet and no one has seemed to answer the question.

More or less Apple Watch OS 2.0 has not been the easiest beta to work with or even the release version does not even appear to work well.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler

They are not available it is unknown whether or not they will available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler

They are not available it is unknown whether or not they will available.

Answer (score 2):

They are now available using watchOS 3